# How do you blend smoothly between frames of video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 10 frame timelapse video (@ 1 fps = 10 seconds long). I would like to add additional frames between these 10 frames that blend between them (so the transitions aren't so jarring) and still keep the video to 10 seconds long.

Comment: See http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#framerate and http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#minterpolate